# Can values be stored without allocating memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have been reading here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Allocation_via_function_calls

and these lines confused me a bit:

```
var s = "azerty";
var s2 = s.substr(0, 3); // s2 is a new string
// Since strings are immutable value, JavaScript may decide 
// to not allocate memory, but just store the [0, 3] range.
```

So the comments say, JavaScript may decide to not allocate memory and just store the range  [0,3] , Now doesnt memory have to be allocated before storing? in case not, as the comment implies, what exactly happens so that the stored range, gets stored in free space, not occupied already by other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment means that `s2` does not have to allocate memory specifically for the three characters `"aze"`. Instead, it can use the memory already allocated for `"azerty"` by `s` and remember that its own length is just three characters.

The immutability part is also important: if `s` were not immutable then it could decide to change its value from `"azerty"` to `"foobar"` without telling anyone, thus also indirectly changing the value of `s2` to `"foo"` -- which would be disastrous.

Of course this does not mean that no memory *at all* will be allocated; we still need to allocate memory for storing the location where the string's contents can be found, and for the string's length.

Comment: To clarify: it *does* need to allocate memory for the (internal) object describing "take the characters 0-3 of this other string".

Comment: This just doesn't strike me as a particularly clever way to do things. What happens if the original string becomes eligible for garbage collection (but the new one isn't?)

Comment: @NullUserException: It won't be garbage collected. As long as either of the string variables exist, all the string data will remain in memory.

Comment: @Guffa Exactly. Now suppose `s1` is very, very long string and `s2` is defined as a short "range" of this long string. Using this scheme, as long as `s2` lives, you won't be able to GC `s1`.

Comment: @NullUserException: Every method has advantages and drawbacks (e.g. taking short-lived substrings of a long-lived value is much cheaper this way). I 'm sure the JS engine people heavily use profiling information from popular applications and libraries as well as code in the wild to decide if such a way of doing things offers an overall benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is talking about allocating space for the character data of the string.

When you create a new variable it naturally has to allocate space for it, but that doesn't have to be something like a new object on the heap, it could be an item in a preallocated array of variables.

The benefit of having two variables point to the same character data is that getting a substring uses very little memory even if the length of the substring is long, and the drawback is that the original string will remain in memory as long as any substrings from it are used.